# Can I avoid wearing Ihram when going for umrah if it's too inconvenient for me, and wear it in Masjid Ayesha after staying in hotel in Makkah?

Tags: sharia, fatwa, umrah

I want to travel from Germany to Jeddah and my wife and baby daughter of 16 months will also be traveling with me. I want to perform Umrah with my wife and daughter, but If I wear Ihram from Germany or on flight then it will be difficult for me to handle the luggage and my baby daughter.

Will it be okay for me if I stay in a hotel in Makkah and then go to Masjad Ayesha and wear Ihram from there?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this explanation](http://www.islamiccentre.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1158%3awhere-to-wear-ihram-&catid=38%3ahajj-faqs&Itemid=88) it is not permissible to do so. As it explains, and I quote,

> For a direct flight from Heathrow to Jeddah, you will fly over the
>   Miqaat and therefore you must have the Ihraam on before you land.
>   Nowadays, the airline usually knows that the flight contains people
>   wishing to perform the Hajj or Umra, and therefore they announce the
>   point of Miqaat on the plane. Because you have already passed the
>   Miqaat point, you cannot check-in in Makka and then put your Ihraam on
>   at Masjid Aisha. This provision is for when someone who is already in
>   Makka and wants to perform Umra. They temporary leave the Haram area,
>   marked by Masjid Aisha, and then re-enter for Umra.

May Allah bless you on your journey :)

Answer (score 1):

Wa Alaikum Assalam.

What you asked is not allowed, however there is an alternative.

I was in a similar situation last year when I went to Ummrah with my family. It is an inconvenience to be in Ihram during flight, and at the airport once you land Jeddah.

What I learnt from experience and what I would recommend every one, and what I will do Insha-Allah when I get a chance to go there again is:

- to land in Madina, or...
- from Jeddah airport, first go to Madina by air or by road

This way, when you are done visiting Madina, you can stop at the Miqaat right outside Madina on your way to Makkah, to be in Ihram.

May Allah accepts your efforts and gives you reward for this noble journey.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on whether it's okay to not wear ihram and go? This post provides a suggestion but not an answer.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, I guess the OP was looking for a solution rather than a straight yes or no answer. This answer is quite satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

*I want to travel from Germany to Jeddah and my wife and baby daughter of 16 months will also be traveling with me. I want to perform Umrah with my wife and daughter, but If I wear Ihram from Germany or on flight then it will be difficult for me to handle the luggage and my baby daughter.*

*Will it be okay for me if I stay in a hotel in Makkah and then go to Masjad Ayesha and wear Ihram from there?*

AWW,

No. Instead, your wife can handle your baby daughter, while you can pull the luggage. It really isnt that difficult, and many people do it.

Sometimes, we have an idea in our minds that something is going to be difficult, but that is only because we have a lack of experience of it. If we make a firm intention to do it, it becomes easy.

What you could, however, do is wear only the bottom half of your ihram on the plane, and then, when you are close to the miqaat boundary, wear the top half, and make intention, and say labbayk. You are now in ihraam, and only now do the ihraam restrictions apply.

Here is a picture of the miqaat boundary

http://www.islamicteachings.org/forum/uploads/monthly_08_2013/post-4260-0-15353300-1376484437.jpg

Here is a hajj guide:

http://alimclass.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/86466751/UmrahHajjAndMadinahGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

assalam o alikum wa rehmat ALLAH hey wa barakato hu

Last April 2015 blessfully i performed UMRAH along with my PARENTS and sister
and i found it very inconvenient to wear ehram in-flight (very low space) and very un comfortable to use flight or jaddah airport washrooms while wearing ehram and it was very inconvenient to handle luggage also. 2ndly its a long wait since you wear ehram in-flight and then get that non-sences slow immigration process done (because of low profile jaddah airport crue and immigration equipment) and while all that time waste keep wearing ehram and keep it neat....
then travel in non-clean bus/car (and sit on there dirty seats) and one you arrive in your hotel you also have to use hotel washroom b4 you leave finally for HARRAM to perform UMMRAH so QUESTION in my opinion its ok to wear EHRAM from masjid ayesha just b4 Performing UMMRAH to keep it clean and CONVENIENT. other best option is to arive in MADINAH instead of JADDAH and then after staying in Madinnah for 8 or more days wear ehram at MIQAAT.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer and to add references to support your claims!

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, Yehraam should be weared and Niyat is to be swore only before the Mikat. Yeharaam is the special condition, and it has its requirements to be fulfilled.
If any mistake, one has to give the fine called as DUMM.
So it is better to go beyond Mikat, Madina is the nearest from Jeddah and wear and swore the Umrah Niyat.

Answer (score -2):

The idea of first visiting Madinah and then going for Umrah is good
1. Reach Madinah by air and spend your time in Masjid e Nabvi and Masjid e Qiba. Offer salam and durood at grave of holy prophet Muhammad pbuh. 
2. Travel to Makkah by train*, car or bus. Wear Ehram at Miqat just outside Madinah city or at Railway station if travelling by rail.
3. Perform Umrah
Never think of landing in Jeddah without Ehram if intention is to do Umrah first. It is matter of Niyyah (INTENTION) which Allah knows about us.

*Train service between Makkah and Madinah started in November 2018. It is running from Thursday to Sunday (will increase days in future). It is convenient, safe and fast than road travel. It is a bit costly than bus. 
You can reserve your seat in train by registering on website of Harmain Railway.

https://www.hhr.sa/sites/sro/Pages/en-us/Services/Passenger/Schedule.aspx
Change language from Arabic to English (for non-Arabic)
Please remember me, my parents and family and all Muslims in your prayers and offer my salam to holy prophet Muhammad pbuh when visit Masjid e Nabvi